# Изменить название файла при загрузке изображения на сервер

Tags: javascript, php

Есть форма, которая сразу передает данные в Google-таблицу. Нужно добавить еще возможность загружать фотографии, сейчас работает так, ниже приложил файлы. Нужно, чтобы при загрузке файла имя фотографии менялось на номер телефона. Пробовал через $number = $_POST["entry.333"]; - не работает.

Форма:

```
                    <form action="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" class="form" id="upload" autocomplete="off">
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="text" class="form-label">Имя и фамилия</label>
                            <input type="text" id="text" name="entry.111" class="form-control">
                        </div>
    
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="text" class="form-label">Укажите свой возраст</label>
                            <input type="text" id="text" name="entry.222" class="form-control">
                        </div>
    
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="text" class="form-label">Укажите номер телефона</label>
                            <input type="text" id="phone" name="entry.333" class="form-control" placeholder="+38 (999) 999-99-99">
                        </div>
    
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="formFile" class="form-label">Загрузите селфи</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="file" id="formFile">
                        </div>
    
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Отправить</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

PHP скрипт:

```
<?php

$input_name = 'file';
 
$allow = array();
 
$deny = array(
    'phtml', 'php', 'php3', 'php4', 'php5', 'php6', 'php7', 'phps', 'cgi', 'pl', 'asp', 
    'aspx', 'shtml', 'shtm', 'htaccess', 'htpasswd', 'ini', 'log', 'sh', 'js', 'html', 
    'htm', 'css', 'sql', 'spl', 'scgi', 'fcgi', 'exe'
);

$path = __DIR__ . '/uploads/';
 
 
$error = $success = '';
if (!isset($_FILES[$input_name])) {
    $error = 'Файл не загружен.';
} else {
    $file = $_FILES[$input_name];
 
    // Проверим на ошибки загрузки.
    if (!empty($file['error']) || empty($file['tmp_name'])) {
        $error = 'Не удалось загрузить файл.';
    } elseif ($file['tmp_name'] == 'none' || !is_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'])) {
        $error = 'Не удалось загрузить файл.';
    } else {
        $pattern = "[^a-zа-яё0-9,~!@#%^-_\$\?\(\)\{\}\[\]\.]";
        $name = mb_eregi_replace($pattern, '-', $file['name']);
        $name = mb_ereg_replace('[-]+', '-', $name);
        $parts = pathinfo($name);
 
        if (empty($name) || empty($parts['extension'])) {
            $error = 'Недопустимый тип файла';
        } elseif (!empty($allow) && !in_array(strtolower($parts['extension']), $allow)) {
            $error = 'Недопустимый тип файла';
        } elseif (!empty($deny) && in_array(strtolower($parts['extension']), $deny)) {
            $error = 'Недопустимый тип файла';
        } else {
            if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $path . $name)) {
                // Далее можно сохранить название файла в БД и т.п.
                $success = '<p style="color: green">Файл «' . $name . '» успешно загружен.</p>';
            } else {
                $error = 'Не удалось загрузить файл.';
            }
        }
    }
}
 
if (!empty($error)) {
    $error = '<p style="color: red">' . $error . '</p>';  
}
 
$data = array(
    'error'   => $error,
    'success' => $success,
);
 
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
exit();
```

И JavaScript:

```
    $("#formFile").change(function(){
        if (window.FormData === undefined) {
            alert('В вашем браузере FormData не поддерживается')
        } else {
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('file', $("#formFile")[0].files[0]);
    
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/file.php',
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: formData,
                dataType : 'json',
                success: function(msg){
                    if (msg.error == '') {
                        // $("#formFile").hide();
                        $('#result').html(msg.success);
                    } else {
                        $('#result').html(msg.error);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Желательно устанавливать уникальные имена файлов, а так замените это

```
$pattern = "[^a-zа-яё0-9,~!@#%^-_\$\?\(\)\{\}\[\]\.]";
$name = mb_eregi_replace($pattern, '-', $file['name']);
$name = mb_ereg_replace('[-]+', '-', $name);
```

На это

```
$tmp = explode(".", $file['name']);
$extension = end($tmp);
$name = $_POST["entry.333"].".".$extension;
```

Также добавь в ajax запрос инпут с телефоном

Comment: Не подскажите как правильно добавить AJAX запрос? Через .value что-то не работает. Хотя, вот пробовал, просто добавил текст ```formData.append('file', $("#formFile")[0].files[0] . 'test.png'); ``` - изменяет название файла. Как правильно вытащить именно из input #phone?

Comment: @Noxar надо добавить `formData.append( 'phone' ,  $("#phone").val() );` и тогда в PHP вместо `$_POST["entry.333"]` добавить `$_POST["phone"]`.